# MODX: why doesn't replyTo work in FormIt?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

Letters come with all the fields filled in, but when I click the email client "answer" button reply-to address is taken from the field emailFrom. Why?

```
  &hooks=`email,redirect`
  &emailTpl=`MyEmailChunk`
  &emailTo=`ask@ru7lan.ru`
  &emailFrom=`ask@ru7lan.ru`
  &emailReplyTo=`[[+email]]`
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.hooks/formit.hooks.email

> emailReplyTo - An email to set as the reply-to. If not set, will
>   first look for an 'email' form field. **If none is found, will default
>   to value set in 'emailFrom'**.

Check your `[[+email]]` placeholder - maybe he is empty.

Comment: this is my input/...


<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="pull-left col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" value="[[!+fi.email]]" placeholder="anna@mail.ru" class="form-control"  type="text" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

With the comment posted here, I think that the ID of your form input is missing:

```
this is my input/...
<!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group">
<label class="pull-left col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 inputGroupContainer">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
<input name="email" value="[[!+fi.email]]" placeholder="anna@mail.ru" class="form-control" type="text" >
</div> </div> </div>
```

Place an **id="email"** into the html tag and it should work.